# how to get first characters from sentence typed by the user for beginner

Tags: c#, .net

hi please help me with a question I had for class: Write a program that asks the user for a 5-word sentence. Output the first character of each word
to the terminal.
**I'm a highschool beginner so I used functions that I know already

this is what I've tried but Its definitely not correct:

```
Console.Write( "PLEASE ENETER A 5 WORD SENTNCE: ");
string sent  = Console.ReadLine();



int firstIndexTwo= sent.IndexOf(' ') +1;
int endIndexTwo= 1;
string second= sent.Substring(firstIndexTwo, endIndexTwo);

int  firstIndexThree= endIndexTwo + 1;
int endIndexThree= sent.IndexOf(' ');
string third= sent.Substring(firstIndexThree, 1);

int  firstIndexFour= endIndexThree + 1;
int endIndexFour= sent.IndexOf(' ');
string fourth=sent.Substring(firstIndexFour, 1);

int  firstIndexFive= endIndexTwo + 1;


string fifth= sent.Substring(firstIndexFive);

System.Console.Write(sent[0]);
System.Console.Write(second[0]);
System.Console.Write(third[0]);
System.Console.Write(fourth[0]);
System.Console.Write(fifth[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach looks quite static. You should try to solve your problem in a more flexible way. Here you can find a simple, compact and generic example how to get the first characters of each word:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] words = input.Split(' ');
IEnumerable<char> firstCharacters = words.Select(w => w[0]);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", firstCharacters));
```

The idea behind it is very simple:

1. Get the users inut
2. Split the input by spaces
3. Take the first character of each of this splitted parts
4. Combine the first characters separated with ' - ' and print it

Depending on your requirements, you can adapt it to verify the number of words entered by adding a simple check like:

```
if (words.Length != 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter 5 words");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Oh ok thank you looks a bit complicated though haha. i was just trying to work with what we've been taught so far that's why mine is veryyyy long

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Fruchtzwerg bu his code is a little complicated for beginner.
here a simplified version where I replace the last two line with a simple loop

```
var text = "this phrase have five words";
string[] words = text.Split(' ');
for(var i = 0; i < words.Length ; i++){
    Console.WriteLine("word "+ i +" : " + words[i][0]);   
}
```

in c# a string is an array of char, so you can access it with 'string[x]' x is the index of the letter you want

Comment: Thank you! i think ill have to use this one, my teacher knows we're all beginners so I don't want him thinking I'm advanced or something